# URL for triggering twilio flow from woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, twilio, webhooks, woocommerce-theming

I am currently using woocommerce for an online store and under woocommerce settings, there is an option for webhook, I am trying to trigger twilio flow by hitting the URL.  but I get error code `401`. twilio 401 error says authentication wasn't provided. I included SID in url but still, get the same error. Does anyone have any idea on how to get woocommerce webhook to play nice with twilio?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To trigger a Studio flow, you need to connect a widget or widgets under the REST API path of the Trigger Widget. You also need to call the Studio Flow using the cURL syntax below.

[Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API)

Maybe you can use a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart) as a Proxy for your Webhook to call your Studio Flow (so you send the Webhook to the URL of your Twilio Function and it calls Studio)? Take a look at the example, Make a Write Request to an External API using urlencoded data, to better understand how to call the Studio Flow from the Twilio Function.

Comment: Thank you.  I’ll go function route, I didn’t wanna mess with creating plugin for Wordpress and get twilit sdk involved. Because I just want simple text message when order is created, and since woo commerce already has webhook option on order events, I rather just hit url to trigger text message

Comment: so i used the hello world function to test, the url it gave me for function when i hit that url i get "Unauthorized - you are not authenticated to perform this request" error, what parameters do i need to pass to url to trigger hello world function ?

Comment: Set the Function to public (from protected)/deploy if you're using the new Twilio Functions UI or if using the classic UI, uncheck Verify Signature checkbox/save. This will allow the URL to be hit from the Internet. Since this is now a public URL, just make sure you put any necessary checks in place to protect against triggering from unauthorized parties.